# zsh: segmentation fault && runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode' [solution.c]

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc

This is a function to return a linked list consisting of sum of two linked list.
For example,
Linked list 1 : 1, 2, 3
Linked list 2 :4, 9, 6
Output: 5, 1, 0, 1

```
    struct ListNode {
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2){
    struct ListNode *head;
    struct ListNode *temp = head;
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;

    while (l1 || l2 || carry) {
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        int x = (l1->val ? l1->val : 0);
        int y = (l2->val ? l2->val : 0);
        sum = (x + y + carry) % 10;
        carry = (x + y + carry) / 10;
        temp->next->val = sum;
        l1 = (l1 ? l1->next : NULL);
        l2 = (l2 ? l2->next : NULL);
        temp->next->next = NULL;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return (head->next);
}
```

I don't know what causes an error.

+
When I declare int sum as

```
int sum = (l1 != NULL ? l1->val : 0) + (l2 != NULL ? l2->val : 0) + carry;
```

There's no problem. However, If I try a different way

```
    if (l1 != NULL) x = l1->val;
    if (l2 != NULL) y = l2->val;
    int sum = x + y + carry;
```

It causes time limit exceeded error in some cases.
Only thing I can think of is that int data type might not be enough to store some numbers. However the input that causes time limit exceeded is simply [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9] and [9,9,9,9] linked list which is just 9+9 case. So, I'm lost.

Comment: `temp->next` is a mistake because `temp` has been set to `head` which is uninitialized. The loop runs if `l1 || l2`, but the assignments of `x` and `y` require that *both* be non-null.

Comment: @Passerby yeah uninitializing was one of problems and I fixed it. Thank you. But could you elaborate what you mean by " ssignments of x and y require that both be non-null."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- `head` is never initialised, so that leads to undefined behaviour. As it seems you want to have a dummy node for it (as a pre-head node), you should initialise with a newly allocated node.
- The expressions for `x` and `y` potentially dereference a NULL pointer. Instead of checking `l1->val` you should be checking `l1`.

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2){
    struct ListNode *head malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode)); // Corrected
    struct ListNode *temp = head;
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;

    while (l1 || l2 || carry) {
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        int x = l1 ? l1->val : 0; // Corrected
        int y = l2 ? l2->val : 0; // Corrected
        sum = (x + y + carry) % 10;
        carry = (x + y + carry) / 10;
        temp->next->val = sum;
        l1 = l1 ? l1->next : NULL;
        l2 = l2 ? l2->next : NULL;
        temp->next->next = NULL;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return head->next;
}
```

You could then restructure the code a bit to:

- avoid code repetition;
- use more relevant variable names;
- be explicit with `NULL` comparisons

```
struct ListNode* Node(int value) {
    struct ListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode->val = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2) {
    struct ListNode *preHead = Node(0);
    struct ListNode *tail = preHead;
    int carry = 0;

    while (l1 != NULL || l2 != NULL || carry) {
        int sum = (l1 != NULL ? l1->val : 0) + (l2 != NULL ? l2->val : 0) + carry;
        tail = tail->next = Node(sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
        if (l1 != NULL) l1 = l1->next;
        if (l2 != NULL) l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return preHead->next;
}
```

Comment: Hi @trincot! I've corrected my code as you instruct, and it works magically. I thought writing as short code as I could was better than being explicit with NULL! Thank you! I have one more question if you don't mind answering. I've edit and added my original post a bit. I'd appreciate if you could look into it when you're free :)

Comment: I can't grasp this part "The expressions for x and y potentially dereference a NULL pointer."

Comment: ...because you had `(l1->val ?` in that expression, without first checking `l1` was not `NULL`.